# Only overrided class methods in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some class `Foo` and `Bar`, that inherits of `Foo`. And I need to raise error, when that not overriding all methods in parent class. Also do not let create new methods in `Bar`. For example:

```py
class Foo:
    def __new__(self):
        **Some forbidding magic**

    def a(self):
        pass

    def b(self):
        pass


class Bar(Foo):
    def a(self):
        pass


class Baz(Foo):
    def a(self):
        pass

    def b(self):
        pass

    def c(self):
        pass

>>> a = Bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SyntaxError: not all methods was overrided in Bar

>>> b = Baz()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SyntaxError: new methods found in Baz
```

How would be able to perform this?

Comment: You can use `abc.ABC` and `abc.abstractmethod` decorator for the first case. Why do you want to forbid addition of new methods? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: What @a_guest says - there's no failsafe way to prevent adding a method to a class anyway.

Comment: @a_guest because I have 2 classes with one interface. First class do some stuff, second just print args to console. And on another environment configuration it will use different classes, that I will get througth some base function. And if someone add function to child method, and forget to add it to abstract class, or to second class, it should raise error.

Comment: @Ingwar You should define the interface. That's it. Once it's defined others can implement it or not, and will receive an error accordingly. But why can't they add new methods to their classes? Again, that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) to achieve the first part:

```py
>>> import abc
>>>
>>> class Base(abc.ABC):
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def a(self): ...
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def b(self): ...
...
>>> class ImproperChild(Base):
...     def a(self): ...
...
>>> class ProperChild(Base):
...     def a(self): ...
...     def b(self): ...
...
>>> ImproperChild()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ImproperChild with abstract methods b
>>> ProperChild()
<__main__.ProperChild object at 0x00000225EEA46070>
```